# Grouping text file data based on some condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a long dataset (a very long text file) like the following lines:

```
https://a.com/
Login: f
Pass: fi
Login: da
Pass: ge
Login: ts
Pass: mom
https://b.com/
Login: xt
Pass: nnm
https://c.com
Login: 763
Pass: er64
Login: zs
Pass: Te4
```

Here under each url, different user info presents like username and pass. I need the following output:

```
https://a.com/  Login: f    Pass: fi
https://a.com/  Login: da   Pass: ge
https://a.com/  Login: ts   Pass: mom
https://b.com/  Login: xt   Pass: nnm
https://c.com   Login: 763  Pass: er64
https://c.com   Login: zs   Pass: Te4
```

Tried different ways to do but it is not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: What data structure is the dataset? an array?

Comment: it is a plain text file. and output will be just the combination of all lines ... just a string

Comment: identify each line using startwith
store url in `tmpVarialble`
and append login and password with that url until new url comes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the dataset, and import the data:

```
data = open("myfile.txt", "r")
```

Then, iterate over and print as desired:

```
prefix = ""
for line in data:
    if line.startswith("Login:"):
        print(prefix, end="\t")
    elif not line.startswith("Pass:"):
        prefix = line.rstrip()
        continue
    print(line.rstrip(), end="\n" if line.startswith("Pass:") else "\t")
```

---

```
https://a.com/  Login: f    Pass: fi
https://a.com/  Login: da   Pass: ge
https://a.com/  Login: ts   Pass: mom
https://b.com/  Login: xt   Pass: nnm
https://c.com   Login: 763  Pass: er64
https://c.com   Login: zs   Pass: Te4
```

Answer (score 0):

### Context

- python 3.x
- plain text file that requires modification

### Problem

- developer FunnyBoss wants to reformat a plain text file with nested data

### Solution

- convert the plain text file into YAML, and then convert the YAML into a python script, modifying the source YAML as desired

### Rationale

- If you have a plain text file with non-formatted data, converting to a well-known data format (such as YAML) may seem bothersome, but it will save you pain in the future if:

  - you got the data from a vendor and you can convince them to send you formatted data from now on
  - you use a "one-off" "screen-scraping" approach (such as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60861331/42223) and someone changes the data, or it has some data that you did not expect to be there
  - you find you need to add comments to your data file
  - you discover that your "screen-scraping" approach was not adequate, and you need to maintain the code at some future date, and remember what it does

### StepByStep

- load the text file into a standard text editor/IDE
- create an editor macro to convert each line matching `/^https:/` to YAML, by changing "before" into "after"

  - BEFORE

    ```
    https://a.com/
    ```
  - AFTER

    ```
    - PrimaryUrl: "https://a.com/"
    ```
- create an editor macro to add a ChildItems key beneath every PrimaryUrl key

  ```
  - PrimaryUrl: "https://a.com/"
    ChildItems:
  ```
- modify the remaining items so that they are all well-formatted YAML with proper nesting underneath each ChildItems key

  ```
  - PrimaryUrl: "https://a.com/"
    ChildItems: 
      - Login:  "f"
        Pass:   "fi"
      - Login:  "da"
        Pass:   "ge"
      - Login:  "ts"
        Pass:   "mom"
  ```
- modify the file into a python script, and load the data using

  ```
  yaml.safe_load('''{data_here}''')
  ```
- iterate the data using a for loop and print the output you want

### Example Python program

```
import yaml

vresult   = ''
mydata    = yaml.safe_load('''
  - PrimaryUrl: "https://a.com/"
    ChildItems:
      - Login: "f"
        Pass: "fi"
      - Login: "da"
        Pass: "ge"
      - Login: "ts"
        Pass: "mom"
  - PrimaryUrl: "https://b.com/"
    ChildItems:
      - Login: "xt"
        Pass: "nnm"
  ''')

for row01 in mydata:
  for childrow in row01['ChildItems']:
    ddtemp = childrow
    ddtemp.update(row01)
    vresult += "{PrimaryUrl}  Login: {Login: <10}  Pass: {Pass: <14}\n".format(**ddtemp)

print(vresult)
```

### Example output

```
https://a.com/  Login: f           Pass: fi            
https://a.com/  Login: da          Pass: ge            
https://a.com/  Login: ts          Pass: mom           
https://b.com/  Login: xt          Pass: nnm
```